# Android: How to do idle processing like some onIdle?

Tags: android, service

Here's my case,

1. my app ran an internal event loop, which processed some custom events
2. I invoked it at OnIdle() to handle events in another Win32 implementation, so that it could get triggered if there's no more system events to process, and try to handle them if there's any pending internal events, then exit loop and waited for another idle coming. This was how it's supposed to work.

As for Android, I'd like to do it in same way, but I didn't figure out how to do such idle processing. How to get it?

Thanks.

Comment: Some supplement. My app got a main activity and a service, the service managed the internal event loop

Answer (score 0):

Create a Handler in your activity's `onCreate` method. Write your idle processing to do a chunk of work and then call the handler's `post` or `postDelayed` method passing a `Runnable` to do the next chunk. The next chunk won't execute until after any pending events are processed.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't help. Sorry that I didn't make me clear. Let me rephrase it. The internal event loop was part of my core engine which was totally built in C++. I built a service to run my core engine via JNI and only service can talk to engine. The activity should simply send user inputs to service and get responses.